# distinct() function (not select qualifier) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, distinct-on

I just came across a SQL query, specifically against a Postgres database, that uses a function named "distinct". Namely:

```
select distinct(pattern) as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
```

Note this is NOT the ordinary DISTINCT qualifier on a SELECT -- at least it's not the normal syntax for the DISTINCT qualifier, note the parentheses. It is apparently using DISTINCT as a function, or maybe this is some special syntax.

Any idea what this means?

I tried playing with it a little and if I write

```
select distinct(foo)
from bar
```

I get the same results as

```
select distinct foo
from bar
```

When I combine it with other fields in the same select, it's not clear to me exactly what it's doing.

I can't find anything in the Postgres documentation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>*(The question is old, but comes high in Google results for “sql distinct is not a function” (second, first of Stack Overflow) and yet is still missing a satisfying answer, so...)*</sup>

Actually this *is* the ordinary DISTINCT qualifier on a SELECT -- but with a misleading syntax (you are right about that point).

DISTINCT is never a function, always a keyword. Here it is used (wrongly) as if it were a function, but

```
select distinct(pattern) as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
```

is in fact equivalent to all the following forms:

<sub>*-- add a space after `distinct`:*</sub>

```
select distinct (pattern) as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
```

<sub>*-- remove parentheses around column name:*</sub>

```
select distinct pattern as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
```

<sub>*-- indent clauses contents:*</sub>

```
select distinct
    pattern as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from
    styleview
where
    ... etc ...
```

<sub>*-- remove redundant alias identical to column name:*</sub>

```
select distinct
    pattern, style, ... etc ...
from
    styleview
where
    ... etc ...
```

Complementary reading:

- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/12/sql-distinct-group-by.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164529

---

Note: OMG Ponies in [an answer to the present question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408037/distinct-function-not-select-qualifier-in-postgres#3408113) mentioned the `DISTINCT ON` extension featured by PostgreSQL.
But (as Jay rightly remarked in a comment) it is not what is used here, because the query (and the results) would have been different, e.g.:

```
select distinct on(pattern) pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
order by pattern, ... etc ...
```

equivalent to:

```
select  distinct on (pattern)
    pattern, style, ... etc ...
from
    styleview
where
    ... etc ...
order by
    pattern, ... etc ...
```

Complementary reading:

- http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/postgres-distinct-on

---

Note: Lukas Eder in [an answer to the present question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408037/distinct-function-not-select-qualifier-in-postgres#20630778) mentioned the syntax of using the DISTINCT keyword inside an aggregate function:
the `COUNT(DISTINCT (foo, bar, ...))` syntax featured by HSQLDB
(or `COUNT(DISTINCT foo, bar, ...)` which works for MySQL too, but also for PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, and maybe others).
But (clearly enough) it is not what is used here.

Comment: I've long since left the company where that issue came up and I don't have Postgres handy these days. But your answer sounds plausible. I'm guessing now that either the original programmer meant to say "on" and accidentally left it out, or originally there was something else inside the parentheses and this got simplified down to just "pattern", make the parentheses and the "as" superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-select.html):

> If **DISTINCT** is specified, all duplicate rows are removed from the result set (one row is kept from each group of duplicates). ALL specifies the opposite: all rows are kept; that is the default.
>
> **DISTINCT ON** ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first. For example,

The `ON` portion is optional, so it really comes down to:

1. The brackets being used
2. Placement in the query - SQL Server & MySQL throw an error if you use `DISTINCT` in any but the first position of the SELECT clause

PostgreSQL is the only database to my knowledge to support this syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think that's it, or at least, not quite. I am familiar with the "distinct on" option. The documentation does not indicate that the "on" is optional, and if I write "select distinct(foo) from bar" I get a list of foo's, but if I write "select distinct on (foo) from bar" I get an error message for failing to give any fields in the select. ("select distinct on (foo) foo from bar" works.) But you are correct that if the "distinct" is not the first thing after "select" it gives an error. So maybe this is just some alternate syntax of "distinct on"?

Comment: @Jay: I don't have PostgreSQL handy to test with, sorry.

Comment: This part of the documentation gives a *hint* about why things work this way. But a [better explanation can be drawn from the SQL-1999 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20630778/521799), which specifies this syntax quite well.

Comment: I suggest that **[ ON (... [,...]) ]** is not relevant to the answer. The answer to this specific question is that the parentheses are just ignored. Note also you must also match the expression(s) of ON with the ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

It's either a typo or someone misunderstood what they were writing.

I don't know all the details, but you can use parentheses as precedence operators (just like in math). However, I think it ends up that you can put parentheses around a lot of things without actually changing their meanings.

For example, the following 2 queries return exactly the same thing:

```
select foo
from bar

select (foo)
from bar
```

It's confusing because the you can also use parentheses to group columns into records, for example:

```
select (foo, baz)
from bar
```

So in your original query, what they've actually written would be equivalent to this:

```
select distinct *
from
(
    select pattern as pattern, style, ... etc ...
    from styleview
    where ... etc ...
)
```

which may or may not be what they intended. If I had to guess I would guess they were going for the "DISTINCT ON(...)" syntax mentioned in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-select.html):

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT [ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ] ]
    [ * | expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

In the first line of that quoted syntax you will find that the *ON portion* is optional, **but** it is also that *ON portion* which references parentheses. In other words, unless the ON is present then the parentheses are meaningless.

So, *for this question* the **[ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ]** *is not relevant*.

Here is some very simple test data:

```
CREATE TABLE bar
    (foo varchar(3), fub varchar(1), flut timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO bar
    (foo, fub, flut)
VALUES
    ('one', 'a', '2016-01-01 01:01:03'),
    ('one', 'b', '2016-01-01 01:01:02'),
    ('one', 'c', '2016-01-01 01:01:01'),
    ('two', 'd', '2016-01-01 01:01:03'),
    ('two', 'e', '2016-01-01 01:01:02'),
    ('two', 'f', '2016-01-01 01:01:01')
;
```

Let us first concentrate on the parentheses. What do parentheses alone do around an expression following select? e.g.

```
select (foo) from bar;

| foo |
|-----|
| one |
| one |
| one |
| two |
| two |
| two |
```

I trust that you will see that **this result is identical to a query without parentheses surrounding column foo**, and so what we find from that query is that the parentheses do NOTHING. They are simply ignored. What happens however if we introduce DISTINCT?

```
select distinct(foo) from bar;

| foo |
|-----|
| two |
| one |

select distinct foo from bar;

| foo |
|-----|
| two |
| one |
```

Again, we see that the parentheses have no effect at all. If we refer back to the syntax this is consistent. **DISTINCT is NOT a FUNCTION** and placing an expression inside parentheses after DISTINCT does not alter the way it works.

So, for the question:

> just came across a SQL query, specifically against a Postgres database, that uses a function named "distinct". Namely:

```
select distinct(pattern) as pattern, style, ... etc ...
from styleview
where ... etc ...
```

**DISTINCT is NOT a function!** and **the parentheses in that example query are ignored**.

---

---

If used the optional **[ ON (expression) ]** really does alter results.

**[Test a](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56a702/6/3)**:

```
select distinct ON (foo) foo, fub, flut from bar order by foo

| foo | fub |                      flut |
|-----|-----|---------------------------|
| one |   a | January, 01 2016 01:01:03 |
| two |   d | January, 01 2016 01:01:03 |
```

**[Test b](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56a702/6/4)**:

```
select distinct ON (fub) foo, fub, flut from bar order by fub

| foo | fub |                      flut |
|-----|-----|---------------------------|
| one |   a | January, 01 2016 01:01:03 |
| one |   b | January, 01 2016 01:01:02 |
| one |   c | January, 01 2016 01:01:01 |
| two |   d | January, 01 2016 01:01:03 |
| two |   e | January, 01 2016 01:01:02 |
| two |   f | January, 01 2016 01:01:01 |
```

**[Test c](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56a702/6/5)**:

```
select distinct ON (flut) foo, fub, flut from bar order by flut

| foo | fub |                      flut |
|-----|-----|---------------------------|
| one |   c | January, 01 2016 01:01:01 |
| one |   b | January, 01 2016 01:01:02 |
| one |   a | January, 01 2016 01:01:03 |
```

The **[ ON (expression) ]** facility is very useful as it can provide the "first", or "last", or "earliest", or "most recent" rows in a distinct list. But keep in mind that this capability is coupled with the ORDER BY clause and in fact unless the order by clause ALSO refers to expressions used by in the SELECT DISTINCT ON PostgreSQL produces an error:

> ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY
>   expressions

The examples above may be seen operating at sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56a702/6)

---

While I don't wish to over complicate my answer there is a wrinkle worth mentioning:

```
select distinct (foo,fub) from bar;
```

**NOW the parentheses do something**, but what they do has no direct relationship to distinct. See "[complex types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xtypes.html)"